# What ist the mainEntityOfPage.@id for a AMP site

Tags: amp-html

Under: [Top Stories with AMP](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/top-stories#markup_specification) are the recommended Property mainEntityOfPage.@id. Should this link to the 'Web' or 'AMP' version of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to the canonical version of the page. For most people most of the time that will be the 'web' version.

Comment: the id should point to the standard web page? what about if the standard page has a different set of micro data since AMP allows only Articles?

Answer (score 0):

I found a detailed description of [mainEntityOfPage](http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html#mainEntityBackground).
So @ade you a right it should link to the main (Non-AMP)-site. Thx.